# Сортировка списка объектов в обратном порядке

Tags: java, сортировка

Имеется список объекта - `List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();`, метод, который его возвращает:

```
public List<Contact> getContacts() {

    return contacts;
}
```

Требуется отсортировать его в обратном порядке:

```
Collections.sort(cm.getContacts(), Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Выдает исключение:

```
xception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sirma.Contact cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator.compare(Collections.java:5108)
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
at com.sirma.Main.main(Main.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблемму

Comment: а в `contacts` хоть один элемент есть? А в классе `Contact` реализован метод `compareTo`? как? А `Collections.reverseOrder()` вы для чего написали?

Comment: если порядок елементов в обратном порядке - это итератором, если отсортировать елементы тогда да - sort.

Comment: Да нужно просто в обратном порядке

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.. В текущем вопросе нет ни описания класса `Contact`, ни о реализации его методов для сортировки, ни сведений о том, на сколько заполнена коллекция, ни о прочих элементах.

Answer (score 3):

[`Collections.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))

```
static class A {
    String bar;

    public A(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [bar=" + bar + "]";
    }
}

List<A> list = Arrays.asList(new A[] { new A("3"), new A("22"), new A("9") });
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);
// [A [bar=9], A [bar=22], A [bar=3]]
```